# Sort optimization in MIPS assembly language

Tags: arrays, sorting, optimization, assembly, mips

I have a code which sorts an array, implemented with MIPS assembly language. I want to know if any further optimization is possible.
`A` is the array, and `A_Size` is the number of `A`'s elements.
The code is:

```
.text
    lw $s0, A_Size
    la $s1, A

    sll $s0, $s0, 2
    add $s0, $s0, $s1 
    add $t4, $0, $s1

Loop1: # iterator: $t4
    ble $s0, $t4, End
    move $t1, $t4
Loop2: # iterator: $t1
    beq $t1, $s1, End2
    lw $t2, 0($t1)
    lw $t3, -4($t1)
    ble $t3, $t2, End2
    sw $t2, -4($t1)
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    addi $t1, $t1, -4
    j Loop2
End2:
    addi $t4, $t4, 4
    j Loop1
End:
```

Comment: That's insertion sort, isn't it? So your best optimization would probably be to switch to a more efficient sorting algorithm, like merge sort or quick sort.

Comment: @Michael Yes. This was an assignment. And it is my answer so far. I mean, I optimized some parts of the code which was given. But none of my enhancements, changed to number of instructions needed to sort a particular array. But I have to reduce it. So *the changes* are some changes to some instructions.

Comment: Well, if we assume that you're only going to sort arrays that contain at least one element you could get rid of `ble $s0,$t4,End` and replace `j Loop1` with `bne $t4,$s0,Loop1`. It's a pretty pointless optimization from a performance standpoint though.

Comment: You could move up the `End2` block to before the `Loop1` (adjusting `$t4` for the initial case). That would save you 1 jump per iteration. Also it looks more like bubble sort to me, so actually switching to selection or insertion sort would be an easy optimization.

Comment: when elements are out of order, you load `0(t1)` into `t2`, store it in `-4(t1)`, then subtract 4 from `t1` and repeat.  At which point you reload the exact same value into `t1` again.  Could you make an inner loop which keeps `t1` stored until you don't have to swap it?

Comment: @user3057789 I can only comment to you, as I was notified that "the question has been deleted" when writing an answer for your question "Recursive Hanoi Function with MIPS assembly". There were 3 problems in your code: 1. no termination of `main` (you already know this via my comment) 2. in `L1` the printing shall be `from $a1 to $a3` (you may have discovered this as you deleted the question) 3. in two of your macros `$t9` is not supposed to use since register `$t~` is not supposed to be saved by the callee during a `syscall`, while `$s~` is. I want you to be notified about problem 3 here.

Comment: @starrify Thanks, I really appreciate your help. Yes, I finally could solve the problem :)

Comment: @user3057789 It's always a pleasure (and also honor) to help. :) By the way it's totally fine to answer your question yourself and leave it undeleted, as it could help programmers who search for this problem in the future.